# How to write a inline function which will accept two arguments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, inline

I want to write an inline function which will accept two arguments in which one argument is a vector.

```
>>nCk = @(n,k)(nchoosek(n,k));
>>nCk(3,1:2)
Error using nchoosek (line 29)
The second input has to be a non-negative integer.
```

How can I make the second argument accepts a vector.

Comment: I'm sure you have checked the manual already but I think `k` must be "scalar, real, nonnegative value". `n` can be "scalar, real, nonnegative value or vector of numeric, logical, or char values". See [nchoosek](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned, `nchoosek` only allows integer inputs for the second argument. If you do want to make an inline function, you can fold the loop into a call to `arrayfun`, however:

```
nCk = @(n,kVec)arrayfun(@(k)nchoosek(n,k),kVec);
```

And use like this:

```
nCk(5,0:5)

ans =

 1     5    10    10     5     1
```

Answer (score 3):

While its probably not what you want, I think this is one situation where I would use a for loop, as nchoosek only accepts an integer for its `k` value:

```
nCk = @(n,k)(nchoosek(n,k));
n = 3;

for k = 1:2
    disp(nCk(n,k));
end
```

Though if you do it this way, then the inline statement is likely redundant, so it could be reduced to:

```
n = 3;

for k = 1:2
    disp(nchoosek(n,k));
end
```

Comment: loop is the best choice I think.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) ,you can see that you can have as vector the first argument and not the second.

So ,you can use:

```
nCk = @(k,n)(nchoosek(k,n));
```

If that helps you of course